# javascript ajax, form submission then page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am trying to validate the form using javascript. Once the code below executes I want to get the the php from an external script to run without a page load with a success message after can anyone help?

The script below works fine and pulling the notEmpty from a seperate function. I need the script to then:
1. if there are no errors produced then pull the php and transfer data from each value listed.
2. Display a success message

```
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var period = document.getElementById('period');
var live = document.getElementById('live');
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var todate = document.getElementById('todate');
var sdeadline = document.getElementById('sdeadline');
var cdeadline = document.getElementById('cdeadline');
var circ = document.getElementById('circ');
var line = document.getElementById('line');

// Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
if(notEmpty(year, "Please fill in Year")){
if(notEmpty(period, "Please fill in Period")){
if(notEmpty(live, "Please fill in live Date")){
if(notEmpty(start, "Please fill in Start Date")){
if(notEmpty(todate, "Please fill in End Date")){
if(notEmpty(sdeadline, "Please fill in Supplier Deadline")){
if(notEmpty(cdeadline, "Please fill in Commerical Deadline")){
if(notEmpty(circ, "Please fill in Circulars Due")){
if(notEmpty(line, "Please fill in Line Listing Downloads")){

}}}}}}}}}


return false;
```

Comment: This sounds like you just need an introductory Ajax tutorial.

Comment: im not great with ajax so any help or pointing me in the right direction would be amazing

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

Comment: Sweet mother of code formatting...

Answer (score 0):

The ideea is to create a string with data that you want to transfer to php script:

```
var datasend = 'year='+year+'&period='+period+'&live='+live+ ...;
```

Then, if no errors, calls an Ajax function that sends via Post the string to server.

See a tutorial about: [AJAX with POST and PHP](http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-post-php)